# Como pegar a variavel de ambiente do arquivo .env utilizando Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Estou utilizando a biblioteca **dotenv** para pegar a chave de API do Google Maps que está no arquivo .env, eu tentei dessa forma:

[Imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLIpf.png)

Só que retornou esse erro :

Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

**dotenv**: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: Isso é normal por causa da tipagem dessa API do env. Coloque uma `!` no final do `GOOGLE_API`  ou um `AS string` e veja se resolve.

Answer (score -3):

Bem eu estou com essa mesma dúvida atualmente...
Mas resolvi colocar uma exclamação após o uso dessa várialvel de ambiente, para o typescript não se preocupar com isso. Por que sabemos que essa várialvel de ambiente não vai deixar de existir ou ser undefined em algum momento dévido ao fato que nós mesmos vamos ter que declara-lá como váriavel de ambiente em hardcode no momento de fazer o deploy ou até no de desenvolvimento.